React js state management if-else condition
What is difference in writing in two different ways below?
function App(isTrue){
  if(isTrue)
    return <ComponentA/>
  else
    return <ComponentB/>
}
// what is different if I write like this 
function App(isTrue){
  return(<>
    {isTrue && <Component/>}
    {!isTrue && <ComopnentB/>}
    </>
  )
}


See docs: https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering.

Rather: https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#state-is-tied-to-a-position-in-the-tree – I will try to come up with an answer showing a simple, runnable example

At the same time, I'm hoping you are not asking about the difference of ComponentA/Component and ComponentB/ComopnentB. (different components with different names)

There is no difference, in either case the same jsx - ComponentA will render.
The reasoning:
a) isTrue is a truthy value in either case
// It is an empty object - more specifically

// let us see this below

const isTrue = {}

isTrue ? true : false // will result true

b) The logical && expression, isTrue && Component A, will evaluate true and return the right-side value which is the component Component A.
c) !isTrue && Component A, will evaluate to a false value, which React will ignore from rendering.
d) Fragment tag <></> does not have any trace in the resultant HTML

Is there really no difference at all? The returned component trees are different (compA/compB vs [compA, false]/[false, compB]). What happens if components share state or App is replaced with a different component that has comp A/B in this position in the tree? Will the state be reset or reused with both implementations?

Thank you for your response. I am still learning React. I agree my knowledge is limited. The answer made is in the interest of practising the learning also to contribute. I would humbly request you may please please post your answer so that many will be benefited, i shall withdraw my answer if it turns out to be obsolete. In the mean time, I am grateful to the you for the points you have brought forward, let me see how much I can learn from it. Keep advising as and when possible.

In your case – with different components – there's no noticable difference, since distinct components do not share state. The returned React elements (i.e. component subtree) from the functions is slightly different, but the rendered HTML will be identical.
If you desugar the JSX, your components' implementation (assuming that Component and ComopnentB in the original question are typos; assuming that the function signature is actually App({isTrue}) to match the required signature of React function components) is actually:
function App({isTrue}) {
  if (isTrue)
    return React.createElement(ComponentA, null);
  else
    return React.createElement(ComponentB, null);
}

function App({isTrue}) {
  return React.createElement(
    React.Fragment,
    null,
    isTrue && React.createElement(ComponentA, null),
    !isTrue && React.createElement(ComponentB, null),
  );
}

And inlining those createElement calls:
function App({isTrue}) {
  if (isTrue)
    return {
      type: ComponentA,
      props: {},
      key: null,
      ref: null,
      $$typeof: Symbol.for('react.element'),
    };
  else
    return {
      type: ComponentB,
      props: {},
      key: null,
      ref: null,
      $$typeof: Symbol.for('react.element'),
    };
}

function App({isTrue}) {
  return {
    type: Fragment,
    props: {
      children: [
        isTrue && ({
          type: 'ComponentA',
          props: {},
          key: null,
          ref: null,
          $$typeof: Symbol.for('react.element'),
        }),
        !isTrue && ({
          type: 'ComponentB',
          props: {},
          key: null,
          ref: null,
          $$typeof: Symbol.for('react.element'),
        }),
      ],
    },
    key: null,
    ref: null,
    $$typeof: Symbol.for('react.element'),
  };
}

As you can see, the component tree is vastly different:

A single React element, one of two components
A React Fragment containing exactly 2 children. Either the first or the second child is false


Things become more interesting if you introduce state into your ComponentA and render it twice. After all, the question is tagged react-state-management.
function CountingButton() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return <button onClick={() => setCount(c => c + 1)}>{count}</button>;
}

function ComponentA() {
  return <>A <CountingButton /></>;
}
function ComponentB() {
  return <>B <CountingButton /></>;
}

function AppIf({isTrue}) {
  if (isTrue)
    return <ComponentA/>;
  else
    return <ComponentA/>; // same position in component tree
}

function AppShortCircuit({isTrue}) {
    return (
      <>
        {isTrue && <ComponentA/>}
        {!isTrue && <ComponentA/>} // different position in component tree
      </>
    )
}

export function Dashboard() {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <input id="isTrueCheckbox" type="checkbox" checked={checked} onChange={(ev) => setChecked(ev.target.checked)}/>
                <label htmlFor="isTrueCheckbox">Toggle <code>isTrue</code></label>
            </div>
            <AppIf isTrue={checked}/>
            <AppShortCircuit isTrue={checked}/>
        </div>
    );
}

If you click the checkbox to toggle the isTrue prop of your nested components, you will notice that the state of ComponentA inside AppShortCircuit will be reset, but the state of the component inside AppIf is retained. This is because state is tied to a position in the render tree.

AppIf is effectively rendering the same tree, regardless of the prop's value. Both components are rendered in the same position, so they share state.
AppShortCircuit is either rendering [false, ComponentA] or [ComponentA, false]. The components do not share the same position in the tree and consequently do not share state.


your post is very correct, months later now I am  able to at least think about this difference. After reading the section https://18.react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-1-rendering-a-component-in-different-positions. Basically conditional rendering and conditional return of JSX are different from the UI tree perspective. Thanks to you to bring this point up one that very same day itself.
